In cumulative mixed effects model(CLMM) both the items of a level column are not being picked
I'm a PhD student in Applied Linguistics and I'm new to using RStudio for my research. I'm working on a project that involves survey data, specifically using a 4-point Likert scale. My study includes four conditions, each with two levels: Opaque and Transparent.
When I run my model (mod1 <- clmm(response ~ Level * gender * Slex + (1 | Name) + (1 | Item), data = Spanish, link = "probit"), I notice that only the Transparent level is being recognized in the output, and not Opaque. I'm confused about why this is happening.
Additionally, I'm interested in investigating if there are interactions between the Opaque and Transparent conditions, or if these conditions interact with other variables in a statistically significant way, such as gender (gender) and another factor (Slex).
I've attempted to change the reference level(Spanish$Level <- relevel(Spanish$Level, ref = "Opaque")
) during the model run, but I haven't been successful so far. Any clarity or guidance from the group members here would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help.
I tried changing the reference level to select a different option, but it didn't work.
